# Strange characters appear after leaving insert mode on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows

I use Vim v7.4 on a Windows laptop.  Recently, I copied my `.vimrc` from a Mac, only to find that every time I leave insert mode, a sequence of strange characters will appear:

[image]

These characters (right after the cursor) don't actually exist, and they always follow the current position of cursor whenever I switch back to normal mode.

I tried this with a blank `.vimrc`, and the issue didn't occur.  However, my current `.vimrc` is pretty big, and I have no idea how to debug this.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You probably have something in your vimrc (which you didn't post...). Probably something in a `InsertLeave` autocmd, or a `t_*` setting. Also see: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to comment those things out and see what's the change.

Comment: Elaborating on what @Carpetsmoker said, try searching for `t_EI` setting in your .vimrc, which causes a terminal escape sequence to be sent when leaving insert mode.

Comment: @nightire Did you ever find the problem?